# What are the limitations of Visual Web Developer Express 2010?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

What are the limitations of Visual Web Developer Express 2010 when compared to the Professional and Ultimate and other non-free versions?

Answer (score 3):

Visual Web Developer does not include:

- Class designer
- Macros
- Command Window
- XSLT debugger
- XML Schema Explorer
- Extensible Server Explorer (Database connectivity)
- Solution folders
- F# projects

There are more features that I don't remember.

Some of these features are available for free with Visual Studio Shell.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot use add-ins. This is the killer for me. I need my ReSharper and ViEmu.

Answer (score 1):

you cant creat table on a remote database