# VisualStudio - cannot execute XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, visual-studio-2012

I am trying to execute an XSLT in VisualStudio 2012 Express Edition. The buttons in the XML tool bar to run the transformation are all disabled. The transformation file itself is valid (the default file created by VisualStudio). I've specified an input file and an output file. The output file gets created, but is empty.

Is this a known issue in VS2012 Express? Is there a way to get the transformation buttons working so I can develop and test my XSLT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I read in [the feature matrix](http://www.vlaquest.com/2013/04/visual-studio-2012-express-editions-feature-matrix/), it is a feature that you can edit and validate them. There is no feature that you can also run or debug them, as also noted in [this related SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3088756/what-are-the-limitations-of-visual-web-developer-express-2010). Usually, if a feature does not make it into the matrix, you won't find it.

There are much better XSLT editors out there anyway, and they are cheaper than a full upgrade of Visual Studio. Also, all the XML / XSLT editors support XSLT 2.0 and 3.0, both of which are not supported in any version of Visual Studio (unfortunately). Consider for instance Ogyxen (my personal favorite) or Stylevision, but there are many others out there for a variety of budget needs.

Comment: That feature matrix does not look promising, but I'd hoped that since the buttons were in the UI, there might be some way of activating them. I'll probably just end up using Notepad++ (there's a simple transformation plugin out there). I was just hoping to do everything in a single tool. *sigh*

Comment: Hmm according to this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms255812(v=vs.110).aspx I think you're right. No XSL debugger, just crippled buttons.